# php mysqli input row number in to alternate column

Tags: php, mysql

My database is set up like this

---

```
article_id     article_name     article_seo

    12            test a         /test-a
```

I would like for the `article_seo` to have the article id within it!

```
$articleseo=$article_id.'/'.$newurltitle.'.html'; // article_id is undefined
```

so when it is uploaded to the database it will look like this

---

```
article_id     article_name     article_seo

    12            test a         12/test-a
```

So my question is what what the variable $article_id have to be in order to achieve this

Comment: Exactly like you show it?

Comment: Is `article_id` an auto-incremented column?

Comment: no he probably doesnt want the number 12 there obviously auto increments

Comment: Do you actually need `article_seo` in the database? You could generate that value in your query when you fetch the results, based on the id and name. Or build it later with PHP based on the id and name.

Comment: I would personally not duplicate data, just query with `CONCAT(article_id,article_seo)` instead. If you want autoincremented numbers for new articles prefixed in the column, you'll have to run an UPDATE after every INSERT, which seems unnecessary.

Comment: I know this isn't the most efficient method to do it, however I really want to know! (mostly out of curiosity), is there no simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is the article_seo artribute the way you show the link to the article page? If so, none of this should be stored in the database in the first place, and instead it should be part of the code. That would help you with your question too, since the link would be created when displaying the data, so there's no need to work around this issue.

If you want/need to do this anyway, and if you are distributing ids in increments (auto_increment), you can use [MySQL Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761403/how-to-get-the-next-auto-increment-id-in-mysql) to get the id of the next item assigned, which will correspond to the last article.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to use the value of the auto-incremented id field in another field, the only way I've found to do it is with a second query after asking mysqli for that value with "$mysqli->insert_id".

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php