# Using id of the insert query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Is it possible to get the insert id that is *going to be* inserted in a query?

So for example, is there something that could do something like:

```
$stmt = $cxn->prepare("INSERT INTO numbers (new_id) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param('i', GET_ID_BEING_INSERTED());
$stmt->execute();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can query:

```
SELECT last_insert_id()
```

to fetch the ID of the last inserted dataset, but you should do it right after your insert operation.

The result will be provided in a column named `last_insert_id()`

Comment: That's not what I need. I'm trying to use the insert id to insert it into the database all in one query.

Comment: Ah, i get you now! [See this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761403/how-to-get-the-next-auto-increment-id-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

The PHP function `mysql_insert_id()` retrieves the ID generated for an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column by the previous query.

Comment: I like this solution (didn't know PHP had this function, never noticed it).