# MySQL Insert row with column value same as Auto Increment

Tags: php, mysql

The id column is auto increment. I want the "rank" column to have the same value as the newly generated auto increment value from the "id" column. (eg. say the next auto increment value is 999... I want the rank to equal this too)

Can I do this in one query? OR do I have to run an additional query to get the auto increment value before

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $table1(id,name,rank)
VALUES('','bob','999')";
```

Comment: Why would you want 2 columns to have the same value? Seems like you should just reference `id` anywhere you'd need `rank`....

Comment: the only thing i can imagine, is that you want to possibly change rank later on, but id always stays the same. in this case, you could set rank to -1 or NULL or the like in the beginning, and always use the id as rank if you find this value.

Comment: `rank` changes and will ONLY be the same as `id` on insert. Good point though :)

Answer (score 5):

You can get actual auto_increment value in one insert using this query:

```
insert into tablename (name,rank) values ( 'bob',(SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'tablename'
AND table_schema = DATABASE( ) ) )
```

See more here - [How to get the next auto-increment id in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761403/how-to-get-the-next-auto-increment-id-in-mysql)

Comment: From a performance standpoint, is this faster than running 2 separate queries? One to get the AI value, then one to Insert

Comment: @Bxx in MySQL reading a row of information takes less resources than writing a row of information, hence `SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT ...` should be faster than `UPDATE tablename ...`.

Comment: Is this guaranteed to be atomic?

Answer (score 4):

`last_insert_id()` is only set AFTER the insert completes (successfully or not). If you try something like

```
INSERT INTO yourtable (id, dupe_id) VALUES (null, last_insert_id())
```

and hoping that `dupe_id` gets the same ID that'll be assigned to `id`, then... no, it won't. `last_insert_id()` will return the ID creatd by whatever insert was run BEFORE this particular statement.

You'll have to do (basically):

```
INSERT ...;
UPDATE yourtable SET dupe_id=last_insert_id() WHERE id=last_insert_id();
```