# Yii2 calling show table status using Activerecord

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'promo_deliveries'
```

Is there any way other than executing the query with the following

```
$connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
$command = $connection->createCommand("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'promo_deliveries'");
$command->queryAll();
```

using ActiveRecord models in yii2

Comment: You have to provide more information, like what is your RDBMS, what will you achieve and what have you tried? [ActiveRecord](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html) is well documented.

Comment: As far as I know `SHOW TABLE STATUS` works on "tables" (not the record/data of table) information, whereas `ActiveRecord` works/operates  on single table and its record/data

Comment: yes, exactly you are right @leninhasda and i actually want to check the next upcomming autoincrement key for the table promo_deliveries by running this query, that would be available in the `Auto_increment` column

Comment: possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761403/how-to-get-the-next-auto-increment-id-in-mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` or `mysql_insert_id()` not any other way to do it so far.